# How to click one of the item in list view and display a more detail description about it in another page?

Tags: android

[image]

What should I change from the code? I mostly take the code from this source. http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/04/sqlite-example-in-android-add-image.html. I would like to press on one of the item of the list view and bring me to another page which shows the product description.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display);
    dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
    /**
     * create DatabaseHandler object
     */
    db = new DataBaseHandler(this);
    /**
     * Reading and getting all records from database
     */

    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
    for (Contact cn : contacts) {
        String log = "ID:" + cn.getID() + " Name: " + cn.getName()+ " Price: " + cn.getPrice() +" Categories: " + cn.getCategories()
                + " ,Image: " + cn.getImage();

        // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Result: ", log);
        // add contacts data in arrayList
        imageArry.add(cn);

    }
    /**
     * Set Data base Item into listview
     */
    imageAdapter = new ContactImageAdapter(this, R.layout.screen_list,
            imageArry);
    dataList.setAdapter(imageAdapter);


    /**
     * go to next activity for detail image
     */
    dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                final int position, long id) {
            imageName = imageArry.get(position).getImage();
            imageId = imageArry.get(position).getID();

            Log.d("Before Send:****", imageName + "-"  +imageId);
            // convert byte to bitmap
            ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                    imageName);
            theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayImageActivity.this,
                    DisplayImageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("imagename", theImage);
            intent.putExtra("imageid", imageId);
            startActivity(intent);



        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to view both in one activity, perhaps the best way would be to use two fragments and then use events to notify the activity to update the details fragment when the item is clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            News news = (News) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(GridViewActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("news", news);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

`News` is a class where I have saved each items information.
`DetailsActivity` is the next activity.

In `DetailsActivity` I have `TexView`s for author, description and title.

```
TextView author;
TextView description;
TextView title;
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    News news = (News) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("news");
    ...
    author.setText(news.getAuther());
    title.setText(news.getTitle());
    description.setText(news.getDescription());
    ...
}
```

`getAuther()`, `getTitle()`, `getDescription()` are the methods of the `News` Class.

So, like this you can make an activity of the detail info.

Comment: what if i already create a java file name database handler which is a sqlite to store my data and write down the CRUD operations, should i still create a news class to store the data? cause when i change to this DataBaseHandler news = (DataBaseHandler) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayImageActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("news", news);         //this paragraph gt error